# Why is javascript quitting after jquery remove() statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently working with Javascript and JQuery (both which I'm new to so go easy on me) and the goal is to, when the form is filled out incorrectly. To add add a message that says the form is incorrect. When the form is inputed correctly, then the "incorrect" message should be removed. However, after inputed a bad input to prompt the additional HTML, when I correct the form to get rid of it, the javascript terminates after the remove function.

Also, is there anyway to remove on condition? In other words, is there a pre-existing method that says, "if the html exists to remove, then remove, else do nothing." or do I have to write my own flag.

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#basic').on('submit', function(e)
        {
            if(!isBasicInfoValid())
            {
                if(!error)
                {
                    $('#basic').append($("<div class='basicError'>Input is not valid! </div>"));
                }
                error=true;
            }
            else if(error)
            {
                error=false;
                $('#basic').remove($(".basicError"));
                //program is stopping after remove for some reason
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    };
```

```
   <body>
        <div class='form'>
            <h3> Basic Information </h3>
            <form id='basic'>
                <div>Year of Birth: <input type='number' name='YOB'> </div> 
                <div>Current Savings: <input type='number' name='CurrSav'> 
                </div>  
                <div>Expected Retirement Age: <input type='number' name='RetAge'></div>     
                <div>Life expectancy: <input type='number' name='LifeExp'>
                </div>  
                <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div> 
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class='form'>
            <h3> Scenario </h3>
            <form id='scenario'>
                <div>Name: <input type='text' name='ScenarioName'> </div>
                <div>Rate of Investment Return (While Working): <input type='number' name='Working'></div>
                <div>Rate of Investment Return (Retired): <input type='number' name='Retired'></div>
                <div>Desired Retirement Yearly Income: <input type='number' name='desiredInc'></div>
                <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>
            </form>
            <div><button id='add' type='submit'>Add Scenario </button></div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just as an aside, as you say you're new to jQuery, have you seen the jQuery Validation Plugin? (link: http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: What are you expecting scenarioCount to do? scenarioCount has not been defined as a variable you need to do this before you can increment it. You can also incremenet a var by using ++ instead of +1

Comment: sorry that variable was in the wrong place. Coming from java I would use ++ but being new to the syntax I was just being cautious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#basic').children('.basicError').remove();
```

or

```
$("#basic .basicError").remove();
```

Comment: The second one works but `$('#basic').remove(".basicError");` doesn't why is that. Also what is the interpretation of `#basic .basicError`

Comment: Because the remove selector is different , the remove() will target the selected object not its children or siblings

Comment: $('div').remove('#basic'),In this example the selector selects the div and remove('#basic') matches the div with id  #basic

Comment: $('#basic .basicError') means it will select the element with class name .basicError within the element with id #basic

Comment: Hope you had got answer for your question, thanks for considering me

Comment: ^Gotcha thanks for the follow up help. I'm trying to wrap my head around all these new concepts, I typically program in java

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
$('#basic').remove($(".basicError"));
```

To just:

```
$('#basic').remove(".basicError");
```

Answer (score 2):

[`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) takes a selector, you've giving it a jQuery object. It's stopping because jQuery will be throwing a JS error because it's expecting a selector.

Try this:

```
$('#basic').remove(".basicError");
```

Or, as there's only one `.basicError`, you can just do:

```
$(".basicError").remove();
```

Comment: second works, why doesn't the first though? Thanks a lot btw!